# CUDA-accelerated libraries vs CUDA Application Engines

Tags: cuda, libraries, nvidia

I am begineer so I dont have enough knowledge. I would like to know what is the exact difference between GPU Accelerated Libraries and CUDA Application Engine

https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-accelerated-libraries

vs

https://developer.nvidia.com/application-engine-introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application engines all deal with graphics problems, the principal use case of a GPU.

But the point of CUDA is to task the GPU to do things other than graphics problems.  The accelerated libraries involve things like linear algebra, calculation of Fourier Transforms, parallelization of general (non-graphic) computing problems, high-speed random number generation, and so forth.